# Cannot get raw UDP socket to work using Python on a Linux machine with specific IP and Port

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I am trying to connect using Python on a Linux system to a Windows system that is listening at a certain IP and port number using UDP socket.

I know the IP and port number but I do not know any host names.
But I thought it would be easy to just connect and send a small message.
I keep getting an error no matter how I specify the address.

```
import socket


def openSocket():
   HOST = "1.1.1.1"
   PORT = 111
   server_address = (HOST, PORT)
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL) ) 
   s.connect(server_address)
   s.sendAll("HELLO") 
   s.close()



openSocket()
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: s.connect(server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
TypeError: argument 1 must be string, not tuple

Comment: please add that crucial information to the question.

Comment: I've tried a few different syntaxes.  If I change it to  s.sendto( "HELLO",server_address) then I don't get that previous error but I get a "No such device" error

Comment: I think I've solved the mystery: see my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to read the error:

```
s.connect(server_address) File "<string>", line 1, in connect TypeError: argument 1 must be string, not tuple
```

which points you directly at your `connect()` call. Now compare this to the official python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.SOCK_DGRAM).

I've noticed that you've wanted to generate a UDP socket, but used `RAW` as type instead of `DGRAM`. `RAW` will give you raw network protocol level access (ie. lower level than UDP), and can't therefore be used with `(HOST,PORT)` tuples.